# Back to old display format in Matlab R2016b

Tags: matlab, configuration, ide, compatibility

In Matlab R2016b, displaying variables of certain data types shows information about the type. This happens when the variable is displayed by typing it without a final semicolon (it doesn't happen when using the `disp` function).

Compare for example:

- Matlab R2015b (old format: displays just the data):

  ```
  >> x = [10 20 30]
  x =
      10    20    30
  >> x = {10 20 30}
  x = 
      [10]    [20]    [30]
  >> x = [false false true]
  x =
       0     0     1
  ```
- Matlab R2016b (new format: includes type):

  ```
  >> x = [10 20 30]
  x =
      10    20    30
  >> x = {10 20 30}
  x =
    1×3 cell array
      [10]    [20]    [30]
  >> x = [false false true]
  x =
    1×3 logical array
     0   0   1
  ```

As you see, there's an extra line in R2016b telling the type. Apparently this happens for any type that is not `double` or `char`.

Is there some setting in R2016b to go back to the old behaviour?

Comment: Ohhh come on Luis, this is a really nice feature!! :P

Comment: @AnderBiguri But it makes feel like I'm not at home anymore :-)

Comment: have tried to dig a little into the groot propertes? I don't have the newest version yet.

Comment: Is that not defined in the `disp` method of the base objects ? I don't know if it is easily accessible though. I don't have R2016b either :-(

Comment: @thewaywewalk But `groot` is only for graphics, isn't it?

Comment: @Hoki I don't think so, because calling `disp` doesn't produce the extra line in R2016b. The new line has to do with the automatic displaying cause by omitting the semicolon, rather than with `disp`

Comment: well, I think when you use `disp` explicitly you override the object internal `disp` method. It call the global `disp` function (with whatever object you send as input pamameter), I don't think it detect the object type (to call its own `disp`) until the _global_ `disp` has started running and is checking the parameters you sent it. On the other side, when you just type the object name on its own (or when you omit the `;`), the global `disp` is not called and only the internal `disp` is executed.

Comment: I couldn't access any of the base object `disp`, but if you read [Custom Display Interface](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/custom-display-interface.html#responsive_offcanvas), you'll have a good explanation on how it's handled. This article is for modifying your own custom object display, but it also explain how it's done for the built-in objects.

Comment: @Hoki Thanks. I'll take a look at that later in the day

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a preference for changing that behavior. There is (as always) a bit of a hacky workaround.

When you omit a semi-colon from a line, it's not `disp` that is called but rather [`display`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/display.html).  R2016b has apparently modified the `display` method for a `cell` datatype to display some type information along with the values themselves.

Thankfully we can overload that `display` method with something that looks a little bit more like the `display` of previous releases.

We can create a `@cell` folder (anywhere on our path) and place a file called `display.m` inside.

`@cell/display.m`

```
function display(obj)
    % Overloaded display function for grumpy old men

    if strcmpi(get(0, 'FormatSpacing'), 'loose')
        fprintf('\n%s =\n\n', inputname(1))
    else
        fprintf('%s =\n', inputname(1))
    end
    disp(obj);
end
```

Now, whenever a cell array is displayed due lack of a trailing semi-colon, it will not include any type information.

```
>> c = {'a', 'b'}

c =

    'a'    'b'
```

Unfortunately, there are other datatypes (such as `logical`) that also display the type information so you'd have to overload the `display` method for each of these classes.

Comment: Thanks! Overloading `display` seems to be the way to go. To avoid having to reproduce the exact format produced by the builtin `display`, I think it may be better (if using `evalc` can ever qualify as "better") to do `t = evalc('builtin(''display'', obj)');` Then `t` is a `char` vector from which the grumpy-offending line can be removed with `regexp` (I can't try it right now, as I'm on R2015b)

Comment: @LuisMendo Strangely, `builtin('display', c)` doesn't give you the `c = ` at the beginning but calling `display(c)` directly does...

Comment: True! It doesn't in R2015b either. So I think it's safe to assume it doesn't in general, and add it manually