# How to fix the decimal place of matrix elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, rounding

I have a matrix of order `3 x 3`, and all elements of matrix are up to 6 decimal place. I want to display this elements of matrix only up to 5 decimal place. I used `format short` and `format long`, but it gives either 4 or 15 decimal places.
Is there a command that gives up to any particular decimal places?
I have idea for a single number but could not solve for all entries of a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The builtin `format` options cannot handle this. You'll instead want to use `fprintf` or `num2str` (with a [format specifier](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0ybtd)) to force the appearance of the number

```
data = rand(3) * 100;
num2str(data,'%12.5f')

%   20.42155     3.95486    91.50871
%    9.28906    87.24924    72.61826
%   47.43655    95.70325    94.41092
```

If you want to make this the default display at the command line [you *could* overload the builtin `display` method for `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828222/back-to-old-display-format-in-matlab-r2016b/39835685#39835685) but I would not recommend that.

Alternately, you can use `vpa` to specify the number of significant digits to display ([note that the second input is the number of *significant digits* and not the number of numbers after the radix point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42380580/670206)).

```
vpa(data, 5)
```

Comment: You don't need the `12` in your `num2str` formatting string, you can just use `num2str(data, '%.5f')` to specify a floating point number with 5 digits of precision. Docs link for OP's reference: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html#inputarg_formatSpec

Comment: @Wolfie Well if you want your matrix to not be aligned and nice-looking, sure

Comment: ah yes, you're quite right! I'll leave my comment there in case the docs link is useful :)